# Loop over list containing maps and create resources conditionaly

Tags: terraform

I have the following json structure:

```
{
  "serviceConfig": {
    "city_shared": {
      "schedules": [
        {
          "EcsServiceRestartOrder": [
            "redis",
            "redis2",
            "redisblahblah"
          ],
          "Description": "daily",
          "CityRestartCronExpression": "cron(0 4 * * ? *)",
          "CityRestartEnabled": true
        },
        {
          "EcsServiceRestartOrder": ["redis-stg"],
          "Description": "weekly",
          "CityRestartCronExpression" : "cron(0 4 * * 1 *)",
          "CityRestartEnabled": true
        }
      ],
      "MonitoringStartUTC": "0500",
      "MonitoringEndUTC": "2000"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the following terraform:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "scheduled_restart" {
  for_each = { for i in var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules : i.Description => i
  if i.CityRestartEnabled == true }

  name                = "${local.awsResourceName}-${each.value.Description}-scheduled_restart"
  schedule_expression = each.value.CityRestartCronExpression

  is_enabled = each.value.CityRestartEnabled
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch_event_scheduled_restart" {
  for_each = { for i in var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules : i.Description => i
  if var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules.CityRestartEnabled == true }

  name = "${join("", [local.multiRegionCityPrefix, local.awsResourceName])}-cloudwatch_event_scheduled_restart"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "events.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
    }
  )

  tags = {
    tag-key = "${join("", [local.multiRegionCityPrefix, local.awsResourceName])}-cloudwatch_event_scheduled_restart"
  }
}
```

I am trying to loop over the structure and only create the resources if `CityRestartEnabled` is set to `true` however I get some errors:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on cloudwatch_events.tf line 3, in resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch_event_scheduled_restart":
   3:   if var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules.CityRestartEnabled == true }
    |----------------
    | var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules is list of object with 2 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

and the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on cloudwatch_events.tf line 52, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "scheduled_restart":
  52:   for_each = { for i in var.serviceConfig.city_shared.schedules : i.Description => i

This object does not have an attribute named "Description".
```

I'm not too clear on where I am going wrong with this, if anyone has some advice that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the IAM role to the question as well?

Comment: I checked the code locally, and terraform plan works as expected. Are you sure this is your current code?

Comment: @MarkoE I added the IAM role, yup this is definitely what I am running!

Comment: So the JSON is defined in a tfvars file? Where is it coming from? Just tested, no errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my own configuration.
The `serviceConfig` variable is defined as an object in the terraform code then we load the config in through a `.auto.tfvars.json` file.
This means that the `serviceConfig` variable must match the json exactly. I had simply forgotten to update the variable to include `Description.`

```
variable "serviceConfig" {
  type = object({
    city_shared = object({
      schedules = list(object({
        EcsServiceRestartOrder    = list(string)
        CityRestartCronExpression = string
        CityRestartEnabled        = bool
        Description               = string
      }))
      MonitoringStartUTC = string
      MonitoringEndUTC   = string
    })
  })
}
```

Thanks @MarkoE for testing, the fact you said it was working made me go back and double check everything.